# Do some arithmetics with results of regexp searches in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

Some time ago @Oleg Pavliv explained in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47615/emacs-simple-arithmetics-in-query-replace how to do simple arithmetics in query replace (interactively) in emacs.

Now I want to use the same method for a small elisp program but it doesn't work. Consider for example the following minimal example of elisp code:

```
(defun Nshift ()
(interactive)
(query-replace-regexp "\\([0-9]+\\)\\.Number" "\\,((+ 3 \\#1)).Number")
)
```

Now suppose I run `Nshift` in a buffer which contains for example the string `4.Number` then I get the following error message.

```
match-substitute-replacement: Invalid use of `\' in replacement text
```

How would a correct elisp implementation of `Nshift` look like?

**Edit:**

I don't see how Seans answer generalizes with easy and readable syntax to more complicated replacements (which I need in my application), so for example what would be the correct (and easy to read) equivalent to

```
(query-replace-regexp "\\([0-9]+\\)\\.Number.\\([0-9]+\\)" "\\,((+ 3 \\#1)).Number.\\,((+ 8 \\#2))")
```

Comment: For what it's worth, doing the example from your link and then repeating it with `M-x repeat-complex-command` yields the following: `(query-replace-regexp "\\b[0-9]+\\b" (quote (replace-eval-replacement replace-quote (+ 3 (string-to-number (match-string 0))))) nil (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active) (region-beginning)) (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active) (region-end)))` ... I'm guessing the `\,` stuff might not be directly accessible from Lisp code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
(defun Nshift ()
  (interactive)
  (while (search-forward-regexp "\\([0-9]+\\)\\.Number" nil t)
    (replace-match (format "%s.Number" (+ 3 (string-to-number (match-string 1)))))))
```

EDITED TO ADD:

Your expanded example could be implemented in this way:

```
(defun Nshift ()
  (interactive)
  (while (search-forward-regexp "\\([0-9]+\\)\\.Number\\.\\([0-9]+\\)" nil t)
    (replace-match
     (number-to-string (+ 3 (string-to-number (match-string 1))))
     nil nil nil 1)
    (replace-match
     (number-to-string (+ 8 (string-to-number (match-string 2))))
     nil nil nil 2)))
```

It's actually even easier than my original solution, because I forgot that `replace-match` has an optional fifth argument that causes it to replace just a single subexpression, and saves you from having to duplicate the fixed text (".Number.") in the replacement text.

There's some refactoring that could be done here:

```
(defun increment-match-string (match-index increment)
  (replace-match
   (number-to-string (+ increment (string-to-number (match-string match-index))))
   nil nil nil match-index))
```

Then Nshift could be implemented like so:

```
(defun Nshift ()
  (interactive)
  (while (search-forward-regexp "\\([0-9]+\\)\\.Number\\.\\([0-9]+\\)" nil t)
    (increment-match-string 1 3)
    (increment-match-string 2 8)))
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem, it just shows an alternate solution instead.

Comment: The error occurred because the `\,(...)` construct in the replacement text is explicitly described in the documentation for `query-replace-regexp` as only being valid during interactive calls.